# How to dynamically change columns position in a grid in extjs?

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid with 3 columns ( name | lastname | age ) in that order. What I need is to change the position of the columns when clicking a button to ( age | lastname | name). Is there any way of doing this ? I did it by creating 2 grids and change them each other when the button is clicked but I was wondering if there is any way of doing the same thing with only one grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2r63&view/editor) how to dynamically set column order using a button. The example should help you in your quest to fill your needs.